# Excel Macro check first two row values less than 15

Tags: vba, excel

here is my excel macro coding i need to check first two rows anyone of values is less than 15 it says 3rd row "pass". now i have did it but it's working only one row.but i have to check like wise entire rows and columns how can i achieve this. guys help me

```
Dim result As String
Dim score As Integer
Dim score1 As Integer

Sub wewew()

score = Range("A1").Value
score1 = Range("B1").Value
If score < 15 Or score1 < 15 Then result = "pass"

Range("C1").Value = result
    Range("C1").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Non VBA Way**

Put this formula in cell `C1` and pull it down

```
=IF(OR(A1<15,B1<15),"Pass","")
```

and then use **Home** | **Conditional Formatting** to color `C` Column

**VBA Way**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

    Set ws = Sheet1 '<~~ Set this to the relevant worksheet

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '<~~ Find Last Row

        For i = 1 To lRow
            If .Range("A" & i).Value < 15 Or .Range("B" & i).Value < 15 Then
                With .Range("C" & i)
                    .Value = "Pass"
                    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End With
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Siddharth Rout Thanks a lot dude :) its working :) you save me a lot :) thank you :)

Comment: @pnuts: Been busy with projects... May have to go back soon though :D

Comment: ohh okay bro :) anyway you save me a lot . i am struggling more than 5 hours above now i have to relief my chair :)